# Move Azure Function connection to Azure Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-keyvault

I have been tasked to move the connection from an Azure function to Key Vault instead of storing it as a Function AppSetting.  The syntax of the Azure function is as follows:

```
AuthType=ClientSecret;ClientId=<clientId>;ClientSecret=<ClientSecret>;Url=<Url>
```

I've created the Key Vault, key and secret, but where to add the above connection in Key Vault?

Also, am I correct that once I add the above connection to my key, I can go back to my Azure Function, go to the Configuration blade and replace the AppSetting value with the URL to my Key Vault Secret URI?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a few approaches to achieving this especially given you can make use of the managed identity framework, but, if you want to use it as an appsetting, you need to use a specific syntax to do so.

This documentation explains how to use the reference syntax ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#reference-syntax

As per the documentation ...

**Complete Reference**

`@Microsoft.KeyVault(SecretUri=https://myvault.vault.azure.net/secrets/mysecret/)`

**Alternatively**

`@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=mysecret)`

Be sure to grant the function app access to the KeyVault secret.  Help on configuring this can be found here ...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli#granting-your-app-access-to-key-vault

Comment: Updated instructions: [Create .NET 6/7/8 Azure Function App with Dependency Injection and the Key Vault as Configuration Provider](https://www.forestbrook.net/docs/azure/functionwithkeyvaultanddi.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was confusing the concepts of "key" and "secret".  Once I understood which each does, I was able to create my secret and then update my App Setting.